When were Oreo cookies retconned to Chocos in the DC Universe?
Manhunter's affection for Oreo cookies (by name) was first evidenced in Justice League International #8, but when and where were they retconned to DC Brand X "Chocos?"

https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Chocos

https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Chocos/Appearances - If you fancy, you can go through the 'appearances' to find the earliest.
